# Is there a way to get rid of skrashers for good?

Tags: startopia

They are the only nuisance one cannot turn off in sandbox mode... I know not to accept Nostros, so the trouble is most likely restricted to Memaus infecting peeps.

Comment: +1 for Startopia :) But unfortunately I can't help with the question. Sorry, but I have a feeling you can only make their appearance very rare.

Comment: actually... I've got a possible answer for you after all (already posted) - you've managed to spark my nostalgia enough to go digging in my file archive for old mods to read over...

Answer (score 3):

From your link [here](http://www.strategyplanet.com/startopia/edmemaumir.shtml) you can adjust the `mood_in00.txt` to make Skrashers less of an issue.

#### First:

Find the default mood, **MOOD_INC_DEFAULT** and set the body value for `(Spawn)` to something like `-8000`. They'll lose health at a *massive* rate.

#### Second:

Find the mood entries **MOOD_AT_BIRTH** and **MOOD_AT_BIRTH2** and set the `body` value for `(Spawn)` to about 500 in each case. They'll spawn with almost no health. The two values represent a min/max for random selection so setting them both low is vital for this trick to work.

#### Result:

Skrashers spawn with a tiny amount of health that fades away almost instantly so they die straight after appearing...

*Disclaimer*
I've not actually tried this as I don't want to try and find and install the game, but this answer is based off previous experience (it was like 8 years ago now though..) and from browsing through my mods in my old file archive and looking over the files I've kept in there...
I'm hoping it's pretty accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer to your question, I admit, but they've never been a real problem for me.

Just build lots of Scuzzers Mk II or III (really cheap after researching them properly) and a Recycler every few sections. With the ***e*** the Recycler extracts from the garbage, they pretty much pay for themselves.

Also place lots of Litter Bins, in particular next to everything that produces garbage.

Comment: thanks, I know these tactics, but at a certain point the station just gets too big for the Scuzzer AI to make it :(

Comment: @Tobias Really? I never seemed to have this problem either. But then again, I didn't play sandbox so maybe my mission was always completed when I got to the point where it would have been a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the MEMAU_TARGET_LEVEL setting, described [here](http://www.strategyplanet.com/startopia/edmemaumir.shtml), but still sometimes Skrashers show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you place all buildings that generate garbage on your entertainment deck, this isolates rats to that deck. This means all din-o-mats must be placed on the entertainment deck. No garbage on the engineering deck means no rats there; and since Memaus and rats don't move from one level to another, the Memaus stay on the engineering deck and the rats stay on the entertainment deck. You may see the occasional tourist drop litter on another deck after buying something and using a lift, but placing garbage creating buildings (shops and food sellers) far from the lifts and putting trash cans close to them reduces litter on the engineering deck to almost nothing. Isolating Memaus and rats from each other means no scrashers except for infected from the Nostros.